# Exception on Selenium: how to continue the script?

Tags: selenium, exception, download, element

I keep getting problems with my code. While I was finally able to open the webpage, click on a button, and download the excel files, I am stuck with an error: Not such element found.

I have a list of URL, and Selenium goes through the list fine, until it meets an url with a different configuration and the 'element' is not found. I would just like python to skip that url and go to the next one. I can go back to the 'broken-url' manually in the future.

This is my code:

```
with open('C:/Users/ovtch/PyScript/source.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        urlList.append(row['URL'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')


def downloadCSV():
    count=1
    for url in urlList:

        driver.get(url)
        # Page Scraping Prepare
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('my path').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('my path').click()
        count+=1

"""Show starting time"""
print("Start project time")
print(datetime.datetime.now().time())

downloadCSV()

"""Show end time"""
print("End project time")
print("Success")
time.sleep(8)
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: It seem that `count` variable is redundant, so you can just remove it. Why do you want to click the same element two times?

Comment: I had to click it twice, otherwise it was not clicking it!

Comment: Do you click it twice manually also? If not, you should not click it twice, but just need better approach

Answer (score 1):

Try this, wrap your find_element_by_* method inside a exception block and handle the exception accordingly

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def downloadCSV():
    count=1
    for url in urlList:
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        # Page Scraping Prepare
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('my path').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('my path').click()
        count+=1
     except NoSuchElementException:
         pass # or handle the error
```

Comment: Thanks! this works fine! Now I got into another problem...the website doesnt let me to download more than 5 times on a row...I have 2900 to download!!!

Comment: This could be a website limitation. If you are getting an error in your script for the download, paste it here

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch and ignore error and continue your loop:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#your code....

    for url in urlList:
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            # Page Scraping Prepare
            # Wait until your button is clickable and click
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "my path"))).click()
        except:
            continue
```